# Why does [a-z][A-Z] give different results from [ą-ž][Ą-Ž]?

Tags: java, regex, utf-8

I'm trying to split the text where there is a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter.

Let's say the text is:

`"Įvairių rūšiųSkinti kardeliai"`

I want to split it at "ųS", but the following regex "[ą-ž][Ą-Ž]" gives me:

`"Įvairių r"`

But when I change my native language letters and regex to "[a-z][A-Z]"

`"Ivairiu rusiuSkinti kardeliai"`

I get the expected result:

`"Ivairiu rusi"`

Comment: I would go for character classes so you only needs to say "lowercase followed by uppercase", providing the regexp engine handed them properly (I would assume so with Java). As Unicode points the range ą-ž doesn't include a-z, for example, so it wouldn't match regular Latin alphabet

Comment: Adding the actual code you are using would make answering the question easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[a-z]` means "match a character from a to z", right? We as humans tend to think that obviously b is after a, c is after b... etc. So a-z will cover all lowercase letters.

However, what actually happens is that `a-z` matches any Unicode code points between `a` and `z`, which *just so happens to be* all the lowercase letters.

Let's look at what code points are between ą and ž.

```
ąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽž
```

`[ą-ž]` will match any of the above characters! That's not what you want, is it?

To solve this, you can either

- type all the lowercase letters and put them in `[]`. Do the same for uppercase ones, or;
- Use character classes, like `\p{Lu}` for uppercase and `\p{Ll}` for lowercase.

Comment: Changed the expression to "(\p{Ll}\p{Lu})" and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`[Ą-Ž]` includes `š`.

```
for (char c = 'Ą'; c <= 'Ž'; ++c)
    System.out.print(c);
```

result:

```
ĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽ
```

But `[A-Z]` does not include `s`.

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c)
    System.out.print(c);
```

result:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```